# How to return records from Oracle dynamic SQL in a stored procedure with ODP.NET

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql, odp.net

I'am trying to figure out how can i get the result of a dynamic sql query that is being held in a store procedure.

The store procedure is simple:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PORT_CALL_PROCEDEURE(queryin IN varchar2,result out varchar2)
is

BEGIN

   dbms_output.put_line(queryin);
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE queryin;    
END ;
```

The way I'am calling it from VS is:

```
OracleCommand oracmd = GetCommand("PORT_CALL_PROCEDEURE", oraconn);
oraconn.Open();
string row = string.Empty;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("SELECT * into result Where port = 'MSO'and Map = 'Local'");
sb.Append(" FROM VESSEL");
string commandString = sb.ToString();
command.Parameters.Add("query_in", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 10000000,      commandString, ParameterDirection.Input);
command.Parameters.Add("result", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 10000000,     `commandString, ParameterDirection.Output);`
oracmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I'am getting an exception:

```
{"ORA-00905: missing keyword
  ORA-06512: at \"BOAZ.PORT_CALL_PROCEDEURE\", line 7
  ORA-06512: at line 1"}
```

Any help?
Thanks.

Comment: What is the purpose to call a stored procedure just for executing a scalar query? Generally this actions can be done without using the stored procedure! Look at OracleCommand.ExecuteScalar method if you don't know it. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/win.112/e23174/OracleCommandClass.htm#i998581

Comment: the query was just an example, I Edited the query to the right one.

Comment: That doesn't change the sense of my comment! Did you see the documentation link I posted? There is also a short sample showing how those things should be done. If you don't know how to properly execute dynamic SQL in PL/SQL, that isn't absolutely suitable in your case, it's another problem, but try to separate the two things!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution worked for me:

Oracle procedure code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PORT_CALL_PROCEDEURE
  (queryin IN varchar2, result out varchar2) is
BEGIN
   dbms_output.put_line(queryin);
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE queryin into result;
END ;
```

C# code:

```
OracleCommand oracmd = new OracleCommand("PORT_CALL_PROCEDEURE", oraconn);
oracmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
oracmd.Parameters.Add("query_in", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 10000000, 
    "select * from dual where dummy='X'", ParameterDirection.Input);
oracmd.Parameters.Add("result", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 10000000, 
    null, ParameterDirection.Output);
oracmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
Console.WriteLine(oracmd.Parameters["result"].Value);
```

This will work for scalar, varchar values. To get result as DataTable you need to change types in Oracle procedure to `sys_refcursor` and in C# to `RefCursor`, (didn't test it).

Answer (score 1):

To execute that query you don't need dynamic SQL and you don't need a PL/SQL stored procedure. If you want to learn the two things there's nothing bad but try to do just one thing you don't know at once. This will help you when identifying errors.

In your code you made three main errors:

1. In your query the WHERE clause is preceding the FROM
2. SELECT INTO works only in a PL/SQL block and execute immediate doesn't do it
3. DBMS_OUTPUT won't work in .NET if you don't call DBMS_OUTPUT.GET_LINES and if you don't do all the needed things to do before getting it working

So this is the C# code you would need to execute it in a simple and correct way:

```
OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection();
connection.ConnectionString = "xxxYYYzzz";
connection.Open();

OracleCommand oracmd = connection.CreateCommand();
oraCmd.CommandText = 
@"SELECT * 
FROM VESSEL
Where port = 'MSO'and Map = 'Local'".Replace("\r", ""); // Oracle SQL Parset doesn't like '\r' char
object res = oraCmd.ExecuteScalar();

Console.WriteLine(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Error saying `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` didn't understand `result`.

modify `execute immediate` like

```
execute immediate queryin into result.
```

send the query like

```
select clmn  from tbl where ....
```

Demo:

```
declare
v_name varchar2(50);
begin
execute immediate q'{select 'my name' into v_name from dual}';
dbms_output.put_line(v_name);
end;
/
ORA-00905: missing keyword
ORA-06512: at line 4
00905. 00000 -  "missing keyword"


declare
v_name nvarchar2(50);
begin
execute immediate q'{select 'my name' from dual}' into v_name;
dbms_output.put_line(v_name);
end;
/
anonymous block completed
my name
```